# 10 elements twice in a 20-position array

Tags: c#

I'm really struggling to find a way to put 10 int numbers ( from 1 to 10) twice in a 20-position array on a random position in C#.Everything I have already tried takes too much time and makes my programme run really slow.
Ok here's the code I have already tried but doesn't really work well.

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) 
{
    k = 0;
    while (k < 2)
    {
        rnd = new Random();
        numb = rnd.Next(1, 20);
        //w = numbers[numb].ToString(); not actually working as well
        if (numbers[numb] == '\0')
        {
            numbers[numb] = j;
            k++;
        }   
    }    
}
```

So what I'm really trying to do here,is to put all the int numbers from 1 to 10
twice in this 20-position array on random position.Sorry for not posting my code before,but I was from my phone and it was really late.For example:
[1,3,7,9,5,3,4,10,7,8,8,2,1,4,5,6,10,9,2,6]

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: *20-position array on a random* ? something like `int[] array = new int[20]`? so far, what you've done? i can only think of iterate several times and generate some random integer then modulo it with 20, if the int[result] empty, put it there, otherwise reroll the dice..

Comment: `originalArray.Concat(originalArray).Shuffle().ToArray();`. Then simply look up algorithms to shuffle a collection.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Are you generating random indexes? Or random contents? 


Moreover, generating 20 random numbers for an array cannot slow down your program unless you are going in really huge loops. We can't help you unless you show us what code you have.

Comment: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework questions have to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Okay guys,I reedit it.Sorry for not asking something well explained.And it's not a school's project,it is a project I'm trying to do for my own.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
        int[] array = new int[20]; 
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            int num = rand.Next(1, 10);
            int pos = rand.Next(0, 19);
            while (array[pos] != 0)
            {
                if (pos == 19)
                    pos = 0;
                else
                    pos++;
            }
            array[pos] = num;
        }
```

or if you want the positions to be random, but not the numbers and exactly two of each number, try this:

```
        int[] array = new int[20]; 
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            int num = i;
            int pos1 = rand.Next(0, 19);
            while (array[pos1] != 0)
            {
                if (pos1 == 19)
                    pos1 = 0;
                else
                    pos1++;
            }
            array[pos1] = num;
            int pos2 = rand.Next(0, 19);
            while (array[pos2] != 0)
            {
                if (pos2 == 19)
                    pos2 = 0;
                else
                    pos2++;
            }
            array[pos2] = num;
        }
```

Comment: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: Thanks for the link. Noticed